# Copy files from a plugin directory to theme directory

Tags: wordpress, plugins, copy

I need to copy two files from my plugin directory to theme directory. I tried with this

```
function plugin_to_theme_dir()
{
    $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'folder/one.php';
    $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'folder/two.php';

    $theme_dir  = get_template_directory() . '/one.php';
    $theme_dir  = get_template_directory() . '/two.php';


    if (!copy($plugin_dir, $theme_dir)) {
        echo "failed to copy $plugin_dir to $theme_dir...\n";
    }
}
add_action('init', 'plugin_to_theme_dir');
```

However, I can get only the `two.php` file copied to the theme directory and not the other one. I need to copy both. How I can do this?

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145254/copy-a-file-from-a-plugin-into-my-theme-directory/145298#145298

Comment: put the target and destination into an associative array and loop through them. or, if you don't really care about maintainability, use `$plugin_dir_1` with `$theme_dir_1` and `$plugin_dir_2` with `$theme_dir_2`, you should notice your mistake now.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. Since it's just two files, I did not go for an array.